# How do I pass in a viewModel to a core block that has been overridden?

Tags: magento2, price, xml, phtml, viewmodel

I am rewritting the */vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml* file. The file MyCompany_MyApp::product/default.phtml works fine, but I want to pass a viewModel into the block as an argument but this doesn't work as expected.

**This doesnt work when trying to add:**

```
     <argument name="viewModel" xsi:type="object">MyCompany\MyApp\ViewModel\ProductLoader</argument>
```

**Into**:
**MyCompany/MyApp/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml**

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool" name="render.product.prices">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="viewModel" xsi:type="object">MyCompany\MyApp\ViewModel\ProductLoader</argument>
        <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="default_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\PriceBox</item>
            <item name="default_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/default.phtml</item>
            <item name="default_amount_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount</item>
            <item name="default_amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">MyCompany_MyApp::product/default.phtml</item>
            <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="special_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/special_price.phtml</item>
                </item>
                <item name="tier_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/tier_prices.phtml</item>
                </item>
                <item name="final_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox</item>
                    <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/final_price.phtml</item>
                </item>
                <item name="custom_option_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">MyCompany_MyApp::product/default.phtml</item>

                </item>
                <item name="configured_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\ConfiguredPriceBox</item>
                    <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/configured_price.phtml</item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <!--<item name="adjustments" xsi:type="array"></item>-->
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

**This works,**
**I can pass this viewModel into: MyCompany/MyApp/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="catalog_product_opengraph" />
    <update handle="page_calendar"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="changeproduct" template="Ecommerce121_FlooringCalculator::product/view/accessProduct.phtml" after="product.info.price">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="viewModel" xsi:type="object">MyCompany\MyApp\ViewModel\ProductLoader</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="showCalculator" template="Ecommerce121_FlooringCalculator::product/view/showApp.phtml" after="product.info.price">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="viewModel" xsi:type="object">MyCompany\MyApp\ViewModel\AppLogic</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**How do I make it work in catalog_product_prices.xml**

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing an issue where my view_model was working fine on product detail page for `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme-default/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml`, but was `$block->getData('view_model')` was null on list page.
Then after digging a bit I added this code inside catalog_category_view.xml for frontend and it worked. Passed the viewModel class referencing `product.price.render.default` block.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.price.render.default">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\ViewModel\PriceInfo</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your own response. You saved my time ;)